# What is the equivalent of a diagonal in a non-square matrix or array?

Tags: notation

I have a non-square matrix $M$, that looks something like this:

$M=\left[
\begin{array}
& a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i \\
j & k & l \\
\end{array}\right]$

I would like to refer the cells $M_{ij}$ where $i=j$, like $\{a,e,i\}$ in this case. If this was a square matrix, that would be the diagonal. Is that still the right word, or is there something more fitting that avoids confusion?

Comment: One can take a diagonal of the largest non-singular square submatrix to be the "main diagonal"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, those entries: $m_{ij}$ in $M$, with $i = j$, constitute what can technically be called the "main diagonal" of the rectangular matrix, though the diagonal of such a matrix is not necessarily as "useful" as it is in a square matrix. See, e.g., the [Main Diagonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_diagonal) entry in Wikipedia.

Comment: Deserves a thumbs up! +1

Comment: The Wikipedia page cites only Wolfram Alpha, which defines the "main diagonal" only for square matrices.  I don't know how widely Wikipedia's definition is used.  I recommend defining the term within any publication where you use this.